# "Get records" element is not sorting the records correctly in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a **Get Records** element in a flow which is supposed to return 16 records in ASC order based on a field called `Ranking__c` (Number data type). And then I have a loop which goes over these 16 records.

[image]
[image]

The problem is that the first record that is processed in the loop is the **10th rank record** as opposed to the **1st rank record**.

I know I can start the ranking from 10 and go till 26 which should (hopefully) solve the problem but want to know if I'm doing something wrong?!

---

Update (adding a coupla screenshots):

This is the order that the records were returned from the **Get Records** element:
[image]

I queried the records using SOQL **without** the `ORDER BY Ranking__c ASC` keyword and I get the results in the exact order as in the **Get Records** element:
[image]

Comment: How are you sorting the results? Can you share your flow screenshot?

Comment: I can't post the flow screenshot as I'm dealing with some sensitive data. If you see the Debug Details screenshot, it says Sort records by: Ranking__c (Ascending).

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - I added some more details in the question if it helps. The Get Records element is definitely not sorting the records in asc order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found out that this is a known issue: [Custom Metadata Type not being sorted as expected](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ0UFAA0/custom-metadata-type-not-being-sorted-as-expected)

Workaround for my case was to add a **Collection Sort** element and use the `Ranking__c` field to sort it in ASC order.

[image]